# Why do browsers limit the number of concurrent requests per domain?

Tags: http, browser, concurrency

I know that the max concurrent requests per domain count vary depending on browser, and that it is a good practice to use CDNs to increase parallelism. But what is the reason for this? I can't find an answer for this anywhere.

Who and in what way would suffer if it were say 50 concurrent requests for a domain?

Answer (score 0):

Each connection takes resources on the server (and other network infrastructure). The limit put in place by browsers is designed to try and avoid hammering the remote server too hard. Handling 1000 concurrent users with a limit of 4 per browser is much easier than with 50 (50k connections open).